# Ubuntu fonts missing

Tags: package-management, fonts, reinstall

So I have this problem, the entire /usr/share/fonts folder is gone, deleted by error. I managed to reinstall some fonts but not all are back. I couldn't find the list of all the packages that are installed by default. Do you have any idea how to restore them? Without them no symbols can be typed in libreoffice plus some major issues like the terminal gone crazy.

PS running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: You haven't provided details are to what OS/release you are using, or desktop.  If you provided that detail, I'd have looked up what packages get installed by default for your chosen release/desktop which could then be suggested. You can always look up that information yourself if you don't like providing the details; http://packages.ubuntu.com/ or use your terminal, eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/ubuntu-desktop  (assuming you're using 19.10; I had to pick a release)

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: 1st idea: You do make regular backups I hope? Restore from backup (if not ... please do from now on. Making a mistake can happen but ... adding another mistake to that mistake is not good) 2nd idea: I would copy them from the live session. 3rd idea would be a reinstall -without- formatting the partition.

Comment: answer 1: I will make backups; 2 I copied the files from live and tried also to copy them from the same folder in my second laptop (same ubuntu, installed from the same usb) It still doesn't work. 3: the live does not give me the option to reinstall without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which packages installed files to `/usr/share/fonts` with

```sh
dpkg -S /usr/share/fonts
```

For me the output looks like this:

```text
fonts-opensymbol, fonts-liberation, fonts-dejavu-core, xfonts-encodings, xfonts-base, fonts-quicksand, poppler-data, xfonts-utils, fonts-urw-base35, fonts-roboto-unhinted, fonts-freefont-ttf, fonts-ubuntu, fonts-mathjax: /usr/share/fonts
```